# How to mock optional list of objects in spock

Tags: java, unit-testing, spock

how to mock optional list of objects in Spock?

Assuming that I've function that is returning `Optional<List<Object>>`. I would like to mock such list.
I've tried:

```
def optional = Optional.of(new Foo())
def optionalMock= [].collect { i -> optional }
```

or

```
def optionalMock= [].collect { i -> GroovyMock(Foo) }
```

it's still returning Optional.empty.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please learn how to ask questions by means of an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then edit your question and provide a full set of class under test and test, not just snippets out of context. Anyway, `[].collect(..)` means you are mapping an all elements of an empty list to something else, which always results in another empty list because there is nothing to map. Furthermore, please note that `Optional<List<Object>>` means you have an `Optional` containing a `List` of objects, not a `List` containing `Optional`s. like you are trying to generate.

Comment: You also did not explain what exactly you wish to mock and why. So please do provide the MCVE, otherwise nobody can really help you. Understanding a question comes before answering it.

Comment: I forgot to mention, if you just want to create a simple `Optional<List<Object>>` containing a list with one `Foo` element, as seems to be your intention, you can just use `Optional.of([new Foo()])`.